# What is the best way to connect between python dict and PyQt widget?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I have a giant dict with thousands of keys, and some of that keys also are giant dicts, and so on.

Also I have a lot of widgets with their fields.

What I need is to show some preferred (by me) values from dict at my widgets. But not only show: when value is edited in one place (either widget or dict), I need to automatically change it at the second place.

The point is, I need to do it real simple and auto, because there are too many values and too many fields.

p.s. Someone who understand my post, please, suggest fixes correcting my grammar. I'm sorry for that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could derive your own model based on [QAbstractItemModel](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QAbstractItemModel.html), that gives an interface to your dict, without needing to copy values. Then you could display your values using either something derived from [QTreeView](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QTreeView.html) or [QColumnView](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QColumnView.html).